# Can I use buddhist year without config in mobile setting?

Tags: react-native

I would like to use buddhist year, but it show gregorian (default by mobile setting). how can i use buddhist year without config in mobile setting by react native ?

thank you so much.
Environment
react-native: 0.69.1
@react-native-community/datetimepicker: 1.7.2